# destination-out globalCompositeOperation isn't quite what I expect

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a radial progress view. The second arc in the canvas is supposed to clear just a small part of the canvas, but it clears it all out.

I used:

```
this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
```

check out this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8QfFh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra call to `setValue()` at the beginning which sets the initial composite operation. 
Just save the context and pop it back.

Comment: Still not working. In your code, if you change the 'this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation' to 'source-out' gives me what I want, but that's not 'destination-out'! Would that be a problem? Should I use source-out?

Comment: Uh, sorry, it should've been 'destination-out'.